# Rails6 how to do `XXX.update_all` with mysql function

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use `update_all` in order to update all records in a database.
Let me assume that the name of the attribute to be update is `price`.

I succeeded command A.

A

```
MyModel.update_all(price: "$500")
```

However, I would like to mysql function(e.g. IF, CONCAT, arithmetic...) in updating.
so I tried command B, but failed and the string value `CONCAT('＄', 500)` was stored.

B

```
MyModel.update_all(price: "CONCAT('＄', 500)")
```

I succeeded when I tried C, but I don't want use it because of the SQL injection risks.

C

```
MyModel.update_all("price = CONCAT('＄', 500)")
```

How can I do that without any risk of SQL injection attacks?
Here, I have to use sql function here for some reasons.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which of `price`, `'$'` and `500` is taken from user input here?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! In our case, user input will be kind of `CONCAT('＄', 500)`. User can use excel-like function to specify the price...

Comment: That's why I'm afraid that there is a risk of sql injection when I do `MyModel.update_all("price = {USER INPUT FUNCTION}")`

Comment: "user input will be kind of `CONCAT('＄', 500)`" - In this case, your application is literally _designed_ around SQL injection, so I'm not sure I understand your attempts to remove the injection.

Comment: You could add a step where you whitelist/sanitize user input, so that only the allowed functions/expressions are accepted. But this one is tricky to get right.

Comment: `> your application is literally designed around SQL injection` -- yes, you're right.  I can make a whitelist or a blacklist by using AST, but I would like to permit user to input not only mysql function but pure string like "$150". In that case, I cannot block malicious strings... Is there any good way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create methods corresponding to allowable sql functions that take the params as input. So if you want to provide "CONCAT(..,...)" then user should be able to call a method like this. You can extent it to check type of arguments are allowed and add checks there as well.

```
def allowed_functions(func_name, all_args_here)
    case func_name
      when 'concat' then "CONCAT(#{all_args_here})"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Here, I would like to permit user to input not only mysql function but pure string like "$150". In that case, is sql injection innevitable? Is there any good way to avoid it..?

Comment: In an ideal scenario you would have to allow only numbers and currency incase that is your use case. You will have to consider your requirement and decide on basis of that. For example if you have a form where users can enter currency and amount then you can approach by matching the input using regex or maybe provide currency select boxes with input field for amount. The thing is it depends on your use case how far you want to go to avoid sql manipulation.

Comment: Thank you so much. so, in my case, only I could do is to make validation strict by using regex, AST, and so on. Is this right? It doesn't seem that ActiveRecord can help me with it.

Comment: With the information provided it seems to be the way forward.